# How do I close mat expansion panel on page reload

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I have multiple mat-expansion panels in my Page to display various Info about a customer such as Address, Contact, Personal Info, etc.
If I open one expansion panel (suppose Address) and then navigate from one customer page to another customer page then also the Address panel of another customer is opened on page load.
How can I close all expansion panel on page reload.
 Code for Expansion Panel:

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="address-card col-md-12">
                  <mat-accordion>
                    <mat-expansion-panel>
                      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <mat-panel-title>
                          Address Details
                        </mat-panel-title>
                      </mat-expansion-panel-header>


                              <br />
                              <mat-label *ngIf="element.addressLine1 != null"> Address: {{ element.addressLine1 + ' ' }} </mat-label>
                              <mat-label *ngIf="element.addressLine2 != null">
                                {{ element.addressLine2 + ' ' }}
                              </mat-label>
                              <mat-label *ngIf="element.addressLine3 != null">
                                {{ element.addressLine3 }}
                              </mat-label>
                              <br />
                              <mat-label> City: {{ element.city }}</mat-label>
                              <br />
                              <mat-label> Province: {{ element.province }}</mat-label>
                              <br />
                              <mat-label> Postal Code: {{ element.postalCode }}</mat-label>
                              <br />
                              <mat-label> Country: {{ element.country }}</mat-label>
                              <br />
                              <mat-label>Agreement Id : [</mat-label>
                              <mat-label *ngFor="let agreementIds of element.agreement">
                                {{ agreementIds.agreementId + ' ' }}
                              </mat-label>

                              <br />
                            </div>
                          </div>                          
                    </mat-expansion-panel>
                  </mat-accordion>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: That seems odd. How exactly do you navigate to another customer? Do you use routerLink directive or something similar?

Comment: there is a search bar where I  can enter customer Id and open that customer's info

Comment: how about saving this information in the localStorage ?

Comment: @AkberIqbal I do not need to store anything. I just want the expansion panel to close if I reload the page...

Comment: @Ahmed please provide a stackblitz

Comment: run method `closeAll` on page reload (https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api); how to know if page is reloading (and not loaded for the first time)... use localStorage to mark if the page is loaded for the first time or reloaded.